# Adding a New Tag does not appear to work

Tags: support, tags

I have read what ever related questions appear to pop up, but I can’t seem to find an answer.

I have over 1500 reputation points, and earned the privilege to create a new tag.

I have tried to add the tag: `vanilla-javascript` to make it clear that jQuery is not in scope. (I have read comments to the effect that `javascript` should be sufficient, but that doesn’t stop others from flooding the answers and comments with jQuery).

I have follows the instructions of simply typing in my new tag. Unlike the pre-1500 point days, I no longer get an error message saying I need more points. However, the new tag doesn’t seem to take.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Do you mean plain JavaScript or the [Vanilla JS Framework](http://vanilla-js.com/)?

Comment: `vanilla-javascript` is **not** a good tag. It is a meta tag, you are not asking about a mythical 'vanilla javascript' technology, you are trying to limit what answers are acceptable and useful *to you*. Future visitors to the same question may disagree and find jQuery answers to be helpful too, they won't care about such a tag.

Comment: @George Ah, that’s a problem. I was referring to Plain JavaScript as in https://plainjs.com/, but I like the tongue-in-cheek approach of http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: @MartijnPieters I’m not sure you read the question in its entirety. It was more about why a tag wasn’t being added, rather than the merits of a particular tag. It’s been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: @Manngo: which is why I made that a comment and not an answer. I was anticipating a 'please remove the synonym' request in the near future.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough. I take your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because it's a [synonym of the javascript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/synonyms):

> [image]

Comment: I wasn’t aware of these synonyms. I have to say that I disagree with this case, as many questions _not_ tagged with `jquery` tend to get the jQuery treatment any way. Thanks

Comment: @Manngo well you can post here on MSO and ask to remove that synonym then.

Comment: @Manngo: that tag is not going to come back, no. Sorry. It is not an appropriate tag for SO.

Comment: @manngo yes, but that's why we have the ability to downvote.

Comment: @Gimby once tag synonym is approved there is no going back as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I appreciate your reasoned, logical explanation.

Comment: @Manngo: I posted it on the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you misunderstand - the fact that people give a Jquery answer where that is not asked for (hence the attempted introduction of a vanilla-javascript tag) is the reason why we can downvote. Downvoting was introduced exactly for this gross misconduct.

Comment: @Gimby oh, thought you meant we can downvote the synonym, which we can do as long as it's only suggested. (and two such downvotes, or more accurate score of -2, will remove the suggestion)

Comment: @Gimby I take your point, but many users simply assume that jQuery is an acceptable option — the `javascript` tag doesn’t make it clear that it’s not. It’s not necessarily an act of misconduct.

Comment: @Manngo if you want users to not use certain language/library/tools in their answer, proper way is by clearly stating this in the question itself, not via tags.